# How to convert Dates with format 2016/03/1 to become {2016,3,1}

Tags: date-and-time

I have a problem to convert tide data with the form as follows.

2016/03/23,08:00,0.89,*
2016/03/23,09:00,1.41,*
2016/03/23,10:00,1.67,*
2016/03/23,11:00,1.44,*
2016/03/23,12:00,0.82,*
2016/03/23,13:00,0.27,*
2016/03/23,14:00,-0.20,*
2016/03/23,15:00,-0.51,*

But, if the data is long, so I must use the command "Import". Unfortunately, Usually, if I use "Import" command for **CSV data**, the Output format of those data is also change, for example becomes like this:
In[342]:= input = 
Flatten[Import["C:\Data\tide data Ota 2016 maret.CSV"]]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w4Xr.png)

My question is how to convert that format to become such form like this:

{{{2016, 3, 23, 8, 0, 0}, 0.89}, {{2016, 3, 23, 9, 0, 0}, 
  1.41}, {{2016, 3, 23, 10, 0, 0}, 1.67}, {{2016, 3, 23, 11, 0, 0}, 
  1.44}, {{2016, 3, 23, 12, 0, 0}, 0.82}, {{2016, 3, 23, 13, 0, 0}, 
  0.27}, {{2016, 3, 23, 14, 0, 0}, -0.20}, {{2016, 3, 23, 15, 0, 
   0}, -0.51}}

My purpose if this convert is success, I can use DateListPlot to draw tidal water level.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the documentation for DateString:

```
DateList[{"2016/03/23,08:00", {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day", ",", 
   "Hour", ":", "Minute"}}]
(*=> {2016, 3, 23, 8, 0, 0.}*)
```

You don't need to specify the format out completely. So we can just parse the string like this:

```
input = "2016/03/23,08:00,0.89,* 2016/03/23,09:00,1.41,* \
2016/03/23,10:00,1.67,* 2016/03/23,11:00,1.44,* \
2016/03/23,12:00,0.82,* 2016/03/23,13:00,0.27,* \
2016/03/23,14:00,-0.20,* 2016/03/23,15:00,-0.51,*";

data = StringCases[input, Shortest[d__ ~~ "," ~~ n : NumberString ~~ ",*"] 
          :> {DateList@d, ToExpression@n}]
```

which yields

```
  (* {{{2016, 3, 23, 8, 0, 0.}, 0.89}, {{2016, 3, 23, 9, 0, 0.}, 1.41},
  {{2016, 3, 23, 10, 0, 0.}, 1.67}, {{2016, 3, 23, 11, 0, 0.}, 1.44},     
  {{2016, 3, 23, 12, 0, 0.}, 0.82}, {{2016, 3, 23, 13, 0, 0.}, 0.27},             
  {{2016, 3, 23, 14, 0, 0.}, -0.2}, {{2016, 3, 23, 15, 0, 0.}, -0.51}} *)
```

Comment: `DateList["2016/03/23,08:00"]` also works (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should convert not only the dates, but also the water level values: 0.89, 1.41, 1.67,1.44,0.82,0.27,-0.20 and -0.51 are water level. Therefore, the format should be like this {{2016, 3, 23, 8, 0, 0}, 0.89}

Answer (score 6):

```
inp = "2016/03/23,08:00,0.89,* 2016/03/23,09:00,1.41,* \
2016/03/23,10:00,1.67,* 2016/03/23,11:00,1.44,* \
2016/03/23,12:00,0.82,* 2016/03/23,13:00,0.27,* \
2016/03/23,14:00,-0.20,* 2016/03/23,15:00,-0.51,*";

{DateList[# <> "," <> #2], ToExpression@#3} & @@@ 
   (StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ StringSplit[inp, ",*"])
```

> {{{2016, 3, 23, 8, 0, 0.}, 0.89}, {{2016, 3, 23, 9, 0, 0.},  1.41},
>      {{2016, 3, 23, 10, 0, 0.}, 1.67}, {{2016, 3, 23, 11, 0, 0.}, 1.44}, 
>      {{2016, 3, 23, 12, 0, 0.}, 0.82}, {{2016, 3, 23, 13, 0, 0.}, 0.27}, 
>      {{2016, 3, 23, 14, 0, 0.}, -0.2}, {{2016, 3, 23, 15, 0, 0.}, -0.51}}

Comment: @meddy, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: @M.R, Thanks a lot for your answer. All answer is work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a fully specified `DatePattern`.

From [M.R.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111232/8238),

```
data = StringCases[input, 
  d : DatePattern[{"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day", ",", "Hour", ":", "Minute"}]
    ~~ "," ~~ n : NumberString ~~ ",*" :> {DateList@d, ToExpression@n}]

(* {{{2016,3,23,8,0,0.},0.89},{{2016,3,23,9,0,0.},1.41}, 
    {{2016,3,23,10,0,0.},1.67},{{2016,3,23,11,0,0.},1.44},
    {{2016,3,23,12,0,0.},0.82},{{2016,3,23,13,0,0.},0.27},
    {{2016,3,23,14,0,0.},-0.2},{{2016,3,23,15,0,0.},-0.51}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No worries! Welcome to the group!

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = "2016/03/23,08:00,0.89,* 2016/03/23,09:00,1.41,* \
2016/03/23,10:00,1.67,* 2016/03/23,11:00,1.44,* \
2016/03/23,12:00,0.82,* 2016/03/23,13:00,0.27,* \
2016/03/23,14:00,-0.20,* 2016/03/23,15:00,-0.51,*";

MapAt[Function[l, Sequence @@ l], #, 2] & /@ (TakeDrop[#, 5] & /@ 
   Partition[ToExpression@StringCases[inp, NumberString], 6])
```

> {{{2016,3,23,8,0},0.89},{{2016,3,23,9,0},1.41},{{2016,3,23,10,0},1.67},{{2016,3,23,11,0},1.44},{{2016,3,23,12,0},0.82},{{2016,3,23,13,0},0.27},{{2016,3,23,14,0},-0.2},{{2016,3,23,15,0},-0.51}}

Comment: Thanks a lot. all answers work for me.